# Binance API. Duplicate values for parameter 'symbols'

Tags: python, python-requests, binance, binance-api-client

Can't get prices for multiple symbols, gives error `{'code': -1101, 'msg': "Duplicate values for parameter 'symbols'."}`. I do as indicated in the documentation [GitHub](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#symbol-price-ticker)

This is a my code

```
import requests

symbols = ["KEYUSDT","BNBUSDT","ADAUSDT"]

url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price'
params = {'symbols': symbols}

ticker = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
print(ticker)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the list as a string:

```
import requests

symbols = '["KEYUSDT","BNBUSDT","ADAUSDT"]'

url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price'
params = {'symbols': symbols}

ticker = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
print(ticker)
```

Result:

```
[{'symbol': 'BNBUSDT', 'price': '317.50000000'}, {'symbol': 'ADAUSDT', 'price': '0.56690000'}, {'symbol': 'KEYUSDT', 'price': '0.00504000'}]
```